# How can I specialize/overload a template function for a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I have the following classes:

```
template <class... T>
class thing {};

template <class T>
class container {
    public:
        container() {
            std::cout << "normal constructor" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

I can write a full specialization for the constructor of `container<int>` in this way:

```
template <>
container<int>::container() {
    std::cout << "int constructor" << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to be able to define a similar constructor for `container<thing<T>>`. I think what I'm attempting to write is a partial specialization of a template function (which is illegal.) Here is what I'm attempting:

```
template <class T>
container<thing<T>>::container() {

}
```

This does not compile.

I am not entirely sure what the correct way to go about solving this problem is and the lines between what an overload and a specialization are for a template class function are getting blurred. Can this be trivially solved or will it require type_traits (`std::enable_if`)? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't partial specialize the constructor but you don't have necessarily to partial specialize the full class.

> Can this be trivially solved or will it require type_traits/enable_if? How can I solve this?

Delegating constructors and tag dispatching can work around the limitation.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

template <class... T>
class thing {};

template <class T>
class container {
    template<typename>
    struct tag {};

    template<typename U>
    container(int, tag<thing<U>>) {
        std::cout << "thing<U>" << std::endl;
    }

    container(char, tag<T>) {
        std::cout << "normal constructor" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    container(): container(0, tag<T>{}) {}
};

int main() {
    container<int> c1;
    container<thing<int>> c2{};
}
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1BXei43Lf8KF0va6).

---

Note that you can easily extend it if you want to have more than two delegating constructors from which to pick the right one up.
As an example:

```
#include<iostream>

template <class... T>
class thing {};

template<typename> struct tag {};
template<int N> struct prio: prio<N-1> {};
template<> struct prio<0> {};

template <class T>
class container {    
    template<typename U>
    container(prio<2>, tag<thing<U>>) {
        std::cout << "thing<U>" << std::endl;
    }

    container(prio<1>, tag<double>) {
        std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
    }

    container(prio<0>, tag<T>) {
        std::cout << "normal constructor" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    container(): container(prio<2>{}, tag<T>{}) {}
};

int main() {
    container<int> c1;
    container<double> c2;
    container<thing<int>> c3{};
}
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pQz3eYZdSgyzTdwD).

Comment: very elegant solution (IMHO)

Comment: @max66 Thank you. Partial specialization of the whole class can quickly lead to code duplication, I usually try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @max66 Added more details just in case of multiple _specialized_ constructors. I hope you like it as well. ;-)

Comment: yes: the trick of the rank type; I had not thought to use it combined with delegating contructor. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

You can't partial specialize the constructor but you can partial specialize the full class

```
template <class T>
class container<thing<T>>
 {
   public: 
      container() { }
 };
```

Comment: in this way I will have to fully (re)define the class, correct?

Comment: @user2079802 - yes; but,if the part of the class you have to (re)define is small, compared to the full class, you could create a little base class with only the part to define/redefine.

Comment: @user2079802 - look also at the skypjack's solution: don't partial specialize the constructor but, combining tag dispatching and delegating constructors, can solve the problem without redefine the full class